# If $2x = a + b + c$, show that $(x − a)^2 + (x − b)^2 + (x − c)^2 + x^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2$ .

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

Having trouble solving this.

If $2x = a + b + c$, show that $(x − a)^2 + (x − b)^2 + (x − c)^2 + x^2 = a^2 + b^2 + c^2$. .

Comment: Try expanding $\left(\frac{a + b + c}2 - a\right)^2$ (call the result $E$ ), then to get $(x - b)^2$ just switch $a$ and $b$ in $E$, then to get $(x - c)^2$, just switch the $a$ and $c$ in $E$.  To get rid of the fractions, you can first multiply both sides of the equation by $4$.

Comment: Let $L$ be the left side and $R$ the right side. We want to show that $L-R=0$. Calculate $L-R$ by expanding $(x-a)^2$ and the other two. The result should drop out.

Comment: I think this question is purposed from Heron's formula. The derivation of Heron's formula is something like this.

Comment: Let 2x = (a+b+c)
=(x^2-2ax+a^2)+ (x^2-2bx+b^2)+ (x^2-2cx+c^2)+x^2
=4x^2-2ax-2bx-2cx+a^2+b^2+c^2
=4x^2-2x(a+b+c)+a^2+b^2+c^2
=4x^2-2x(2x)+a^2+b^2+c^2
=4x^2-(4x^2)+a^2+b^2+c^2
=a^2+b^2+c^2

Comment: I'm downvoting this question because the user has not shown any work or attempt at solving.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the formula $(a-b)^2=a^2-2ab+b^2$ we have
$$(x − a)^2 + (x − b)^2 + (x − c)^2 + x^2 = x^2-2ax+a^2+ x^2-2bx+ b^2 +x^2-2cx+ c^2+ x^2=4x^2-2x(a+b+c)+a^2+b^2+c^2=4x^2-2x\cdot 2x+a^2+b^2+c^2=a^2+b^2+c^2$$

Comment: Thank You.This helped a lot.

Answer (score 0):

we can set $x=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$ then we get $x-a=\frac{-a+b+c}{2}=s-a$ with $s=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$ thus we have
$$(s-a)^2+(s-b)^2+(s-c)^2=3s^2-2sa-2sb-2sc+a^2+b^2+c^2+s^2=a^2+b^2+c^2$$

Comment: This seems like an interesting way to approach the problem. I will attempt this method as well. Thank you for your help.

Comment: Introducing $s$ because $s=x$??

Answer (score 0):

We need to show that 
$$(x-a)^2+(x-b)^2+(x-c)^2+x^2-a^2-b^2-c^2=0$$
Expanding this out we get
$$x^2-2ax+a^2+x^2-2bx+b^2+x^2-2cx+c^2+x^2-a^2-b^2-c^2=0$$
Combining terms we get
$$4x^2-2ax-2bx-2cx=0\qquad(1)$$
Now we are given that $2x=a+b+c$ which is equivalent to $x=\frac{a+b+c}{2}$.  Substituting this in $(1)$ we have
$$4\left(\frac{a+b+c}{2}\right)^2-a(a+b+c)-b(a+b+c)-c(a+b+c)=0.$$
We can factor out the $2$ in the denominator like so:
$$4\left(\frac12\right)^2(a+b+c)^2-a(a+b+c)-b(a+b+c)-c(a+b+c)=0$$
Now we can expand once again we arrive at
$$a^2+2ab+2ac+b^2+2bc+c^2-a^2-ab-ac-ab-b^2-bc-ac-bc-c^2=0$$
Now you can verify yourself that indeed the left hand side is $0$.  This may be the brute force way to do it, but it does show what was intended.

Answer (score 0):

This is equivalent to showing that
$$
(x − a)^2 + (x − b)^2 + (x − c)^2 + x^2 - a^2 - b^2 - c^2 = 0
$$
Now
$$
(x-r)^2-r^2=(x-r-r)(x-r+r)=x(x-2r)
$$
so we can rewrite the expression on the left hand side as
$$
x(x-2a)+x(x-2b)+x(x-2c)+x^2
$$
Collect $x$:
$$
x(x-2a+x-2b+x-2c+x)=x(4x-2a-2b-2c)=2x(2x-a-b-c)=0
$$